# How to programatically get total used space of Amazon S3 account

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have integrated AWS SDK for .NET in my desktop application. I am able to create bucket and upload objects also. As we all know Amazon allowed only 5GB storage for free users. I am doing these by C# code.

Now I want to know that how much space I have used or calculate total free space for storage. Is it possible to get this by using AWS SDK for .NET?

If yes then please suggest me that would be much appreciated, else tell me another way to achieve this if any.And one more thing that if my query is not clear then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudWatch supplies metrics on space consumed by each Amazon S3 bucket. Both size and number of objects are available.

See: [Monitoring Amazon S3 with Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html)

Here's an example of extracting metrics via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace "AWS/S3" --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=MYBUCKET Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage --region ap-southeast-2  --start-time $(date -d yesterday -I) --end-time $(date -d today -I) --period 3600 --statistics Average
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply,way suggested by you can done by going to AWS console page but i want to do it by C# code. How to do this?